# Deriving Preference Relations

Tags: proof-writing, economics

I have actors A and B who have a preference relations $\succeq_A$ and $\succeq_B$ on a set $X$. Both are complete and transitive. Actor A will report Actor B's preferences as his own if Actor B specifies a strict preference $\succ$ for any items $x, y \in X$. However, if Actor B is indifferent between any items $x, y  \in X$, then Actor A will reveal his preferences, leading to a preference relation $\succeq_C$.

I know that a complete relation is defined as any relation that for any $x, y  \in X$, we have that $x\succeq y$, $y\succeq x$ or both.

A transitive relation is also defined as any relation that for any $x, y, z \in X$, if $x\succeq y$ and $y\succeq z$, then $x\succeq z$.

How would I go about proving that $\succeq_c$ is both complete and transitive?

Comment: In other words (without the fanciful decription) $x \succeq y$ if and only if ($ x \succeq_B y$ or ($x\; \sim_B \;y$ and $x \succeq_A y$)). Was your difficulty in translating the words into relationships, or do you not see how go forward from here?

Comment: @PaulSinclair I've never done any proofs of this sort before (or really ever, for that matter), so I'm really at a loss with how to even progress with this problem. I would sincerely appreciate any help you had to offer. Also, as for your comment, shouldn't it be $x\succ y$? A strong preference implies a weak one, but I didn't think it worked in reverse.

Comment: It should be: $x \succeq y$ if and only if ($x\succ_B y$ or ( $x \sim_B y$ and $x \succeq_A y$)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that the relation is complete, let $x, y \in X$. Because $\succeq_B$ is complete, you know that either $x \succeq_B y$ or $y \succeq_B x$. If the latter is true, we can swap the labels on $x$ and $y$. So we can assume without loss of generality that $x \succeq_B y$. There are still two cases: Either $x \succ_B y$ or $x \sim_B y$. If the former is true, then $x \succ_C y$. If the latter is true, then by the completeness of $\succeq_A$, we have either $x \succeq_A y$ or $y \succeq_A x$. So either $x \succeq_C y$ or $y \succeq_C x$. In all cases, either $x \succeq_C y$ or $y \succeq_C x$. So $\succeq_C$ is complete.

The proof for transitivity follows a similar pattern. for any $x, y, z \in X$ with $x \succeq_C y$ and $y \succeq_C z$, if you examine all the possible cases, and recall that $x \sim y$ means ($x \succeq y$ and $y \succeq x$), then in each case you find that it always ends up with $x \succeq_C z$.

Comment: I mentally went through each case and checked; they all make sense to me. I really appreciate your help! Do you have any general tips for approaching proof-writing?

Comment: Just that you should write a proof as if explaining to someone who knows only the previous definitions and theorems, but has never even thought about the matter at hand, and it is your job to convince them it is true. In fact, one thing that has always worked well for me is that whenever I learn something new, I automatically rehearse in my head how I would explain it to someone else.